# issue with wordpress post title/caption

Tags: wordpress

I have taken over a Wordpress site and one of the things i have been asked to look at is an issue where the number 123 is added to the end of a post title as per below.

The site is using the Charity Hub theme from Goodlayers, however, the client cannot find their account details to get help from them.

I have looked everywhere but cannot find out why the 123 is appended to the title.

Any help much appreciated

[image]

Comment: please share your link

Comment: http://www.magicalgetawayfoundation.org/blog/

Comment: ok. please find this "gdlr-ux gdlr-blog-full-ux" class in current active theme files and folder.

Comment: thanks, used some javascript to remove the last 3 characters